# gfortran Deallocation segmentation fault

Tags: memory-management, compiler-construction, fortran, gfortran

Compiling this with gfortran, produces four 'ok':

```
  TYPE TypeThree
     INTEGER i
     REAL*8 a
     REAL*8, ALLOCATABLE :: aa(:)
  END TYPE TypeThree

  TYPE TypeTwo 
     TYPE(TypeThree), ALLOCATABLE :: b
  END TYPE TypeTwo

  TYPE TypeOne
     TYPE (TypeTwo), ALLOCATABLE :: c(:)
  END TYPE TypeOne

  TYPE(TypeOne), ALLOCATABLE :: d(:)

  allocate(d(2))
  print *, 'ok'
  deallocate(d)
  print *, 'ok'
  allocate(d(2))
  print *, 'ok'
  allocate(d(1)%c(2))
  print *, 'ok'
  deallocate(d(1)%c)
  print *, 'ok'

  end
```

and it produces a segmentation fault  when trying to deallocate `d(1)%c`. Using `ifort`, resolves the issue. Removing `INTEGER i` under `typeThree` resolves this issue. Letting the compiler do deallocation (commenting out `deallocate(d(1)%c)`) resolve the issue. Any idea would be appreciated. Using

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

doesn't help.

Also:

```
$ gfortran -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

Comment: Works on gfortran 4.8.0.

Comment: Isn't there a problem with ALLOCATABLE :: b ? (missing rank, or maybe it should be a pointer ?). Not sure it has anysthing to do with your problem, but I was curious about this.

Comment: @arbautjc: not really, allocatable scalar variables (including UDT components) were introduced in Fortran 2003.

Comment: Ah, ok, I had not seen this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [bug with gfortran (until gfortran 4.6 included)](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55867), upgrade your compiler to 4.7 or higher version and the problem should disapear.